# emacs auctex tabular vertical alignment of & cells

Tags: tables, emacs, auctex

is there an emacs auctex macro or extension that auto-aligns vertically cells in a tabular?  I am thinking of one where I put my cursor anywhere into this table

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
x & 123456789 & c \\
2345 & 2345 & 2345 \\
\end{tabular}
```

via `M-X tabular-magic` (haha), it reformats the table to

```
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
x    & 123456789 &    c \\
2345 &   2345    & 2345 \\
\end{tabular}
```

I know it could get tricky with multicolumns, but this would be helpful enough.

sincerely,

/iaw

Comment: `M-x align-current`

Comment: @Thérèse this seems to be the answer (it works for me). Maybe you could add some context and then post it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the function `align-regexp` from `align.el` library supplied by Emacs itself.  With cursor in the table, hit <kbd>C-c .</kbd> to mark the environment.  Now hit <kbd>C-u M-x align-regexp RET</kbd> and append `&` to the suggested regexp in the minibuffer (which should look like this `\(\s-*\)&`), hit <kbd>RET</kbd> 2 times and finally <kbd>y</kbd> to repeat the procedure through the line.  This changes your environment to this:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
x    & 123456789 & c \\
2345 & 2345      & 2345 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Now mark the table again and do <kbd>M-x align-regexp RET \\ RET</kbd>.  Note that you have to enter  `\\` (space before backslash) in order to catch the right macros, or use `\\\\$` to match 2 backslashes at the end of a line.  The final result looks like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  x    & 123456789 & c    \\
  2345 & 2345      & 2345 \\
\end{tabular}
```

---

You can also automate this by defining a function like this to your init.el and assign it to a key binding in LaTeX-mode:

```lisp
(defun iw/tabular-magic ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (string= (LaTeX-current-environment) "document")
    (let ((s (make-marker))
          (e (make-marker)))
      (set-marker s (save-excursion
                      (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
                      (forward-line)
                      (point)))
      (set-marker e (save-excursion
                      (LaTeX-find-matching-end)
                      (forward-line -1)
                      (end-of-line)
                      (point)))
      ;; Delete the next 2 lines if you don't like indenting and removal
      ;; of whitespaces:
      (LaTeX-fill-environment nil)
      (whitespace-cleanup-region s e)
      (align-regexp s e "\\(\\s-*\\)&" 1 1 t)
      (align-regexp s e "\\(\\s-*\\)\\\\\\\\")
      (set-marker s nil)
      (set-marker e nil))))

;; Choose a key binding for LaTeX mode:
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c e") #'iw/tabular-magic)))
```

Comment: thank you.  works good.  I marked it as solved.  would it be possible to write down a macro for the init.el that has this all built in?

Comment: @ivoWelch - See updated answer.

Comment: fantastic.  thank you!  best, /iaw

Comment: @ArashEsbati Would it be possible to align it when `TeX-fold-mode` is applied since it  changes original length of special words on the buffer, please see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/70155/18414

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks!