# How can I vertical align of & cells in emacs auctex if a line ends with \hline?

Tags: tables, emacs, auctex

I am using following answer for formatting a table [emacs auctex tabular vertical alignment of & cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557976/127048). It works like a magic as its function name `iw/tabular-magic`.

As a minor difference I want a have a line in between each item. When I do that using `\hline`, I observe that if a line ends with `\\ \hline` its format gets messed up.

Original:

```
\begin{longtable}{| p{.10\textwidth} | p{.85\textwidth} |}\hline
    \textbf{Symbol}              & \textbf{Meaning}               \\ \hline
    $J$        & Set of jobs            \\ \hline
    $D$                   & Set of data files \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
```

After it is formatted:

```
\begin{longtable}{| p{.10\textwidth} | p{.85\textwidth} |}\hline
    \textbf{Symbol}   & \textbf{Meaning}  \\ \hline $J$ & Set of jobs      \\ \hline $D$           & Set of
    data files 
\end{longtable}
```

Without `\hline` its formatted output:

```
\begin{longtable}{| p{.10\textwidth} | p{.85\textwidth} |}\hline
    \textbf{Symbol}                                                            & \textbf{Meaning}                                                                      \\
    $J$     & Set of Jobs        \\
    $D$     & Set of data files  \\
\end{longtable}
```

How can I vertical align of & celss in emacs auctex if a line ends with `\hline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you don't have the following line in your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

With the line in your init file, AUCTeX sees the packages in your .tex file and loads its support files for it, in this case `longtable.el` which contains this:

```lisp
(add-to-list (make-local-variable 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list)
             '("longtable" LaTeX-indent-tabular) t)
```

This line tells AUCTeX how to fill the content in a longtable.  Without this line, the function call `(LaTeX-fill-environment nil)` breaks the formatting.

So either use `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` (which is highly recommended) or try the function with the line commented out:

```lisp
(defun iw/tabular-magic ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (string= (LaTeX-current-environment) "document")
    (let ((s (make-marker))
          (e (make-marker)))
      (set-marker s (save-excursion
                      (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
                      (forward-line)
                      (point)))
      (set-marker e (save-excursion
                      (LaTeX-find-matching-end)
                      (forward-line -1)
                      (end-of-line)
                      (point)))
      ;; Delete the next 2 lines if you don't like indenting and removal
      ;; of whitespaces:
      ;; (LaTeX-fill-environment nil)
      (whitespace-cleanup-region s e)
      (align-regexp s e "\\(\\s-*\\)&" 1 1 t)
      (align-regexp s e "\\(\\s-*\\)\\\\\\\\")
      (set-marker s nil)
      (set-marker e nil))))
```

Comment: Using `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` and commenting out `(LaTeX-fill-environment nil)` fixed the problem. But for the `make-local-variable` I am having following error: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable LaTeX-indent-environment-list)`, is it normal?

Comment: The part `(add-to-list (make-local-variable ...` is not intended for your .emacs, so remove it.  That code is part of `longtable.el` and was meant for demonstration purposes only.